# How can I pre-split a table in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am storing data in HBase having 5 region servers. I am using md5 hash of url as my row keys. Currently all the data is getting stored in one region server only. So I want to pre-split the regions so that data will go uniformly across all region server.
I want to have table split into five regions by first character of a rowkey, so that data with rowkey starting from 0 to 3 goes in 1st region server, 3-6 to 2nd , 7-9 to 3rd, a-d to 4th, d-f to 5th.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can provide a SPLITS property when creating the table.

```
create 'tableName', 'cf1', {SPLITS => ['3','6','9','d']}
```

The 4 split points will generate 5 regions.

Please be noticed that HBase's [DefaultLoadBalancer](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/master/DefaultLoadBalancer.html) doesn't guarantee a 100% even distribution between regionservers, it could happen that a regionserver hosts multiple regions from the same table.

For more information about how it works take a look at [this](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/master/DefaultLoadBalancer.html#balanceCluster(java.util.Map)):

> ```
> public List<RegionPlan> balanceCluster(Map<ServerName,List<HRegionInfo>> clusterState)
> ```
>
> Generate a global load balancing plan according to the specified map
>   of server information to the most loaded regions of each server. The
>   load balancing invariant is that all servers are within 1 region of
>   the average number of regions per server. If the average is an integer
>   number, all servers will be balanced to the average. Otherwise, all
>   servers will have either floor(average) or ceiling(average) regions.
>   HBASE-3609 Modeled regionsToMove using Guava's MinMaxPriorityQueue so
>   that we can fetch from both ends of the queue. At the beginning, we
>   check whether there was empty region server just discovered by Master.
>   If so, we alternately choose new / old regions from head / tail of
>   regionsToMove, respectively. This alternation avoids clustering young
>   regions on the newly discovered region server. Otherwise, we choose
>   new regions from head of regionsToMove. Another improvement from
>   HBASE-3609 is that we assign regions from regionsToMove to underloaded
>   servers in round-robin fashion. Previously one underloaded server
>   would be filled before we move onto the next underloaded server,
>   leading to clustering of young regions. Finally, we randomly shuffle
>   underloaded servers so that they receive offloaded regions relatively
>   evenly across calls to balanceCluster(). The algorithm is currently
>   implemented as such:
>
> 1. Determine the two valid numbers of regions each server should have, MIN=floor(average) and MAX=ceiling(average).
> 2. Iterate down the most loaded servers, shedding regions from each so each server hosts exactly MAX regions. Stop once you reach a server
>      that already has <= MAX regions. Order the regions to move from most
>      recent to least.
> 3. Iterate down the least loaded servers, assigning regions so each server has exactly MIN regions. Stop once you reach a server that
>      already has >= MIN regions. Regions being assigned to underloaded
>      servers are those that were shed in the previous step. It is possible
>      that there were not enough regions shed to fill each underloaded
>      server to MIN. If so we end up with a number of regions required to do
>      so, neededRegions. It is also possible that we were able to fill each
>      underloaded but ended up with regions that were unassigned from
>      overloaded servers but that still do not have assignment. If neither
>      of these conditions hold (no regions needed to fill the underloaded
>      servers, no regions leftover from overloaded servers), we are done and
>      return. Otherwise we handle these cases below.
> 4. If neededRegions is non-zero (still have underloaded servers), we iterate the most loaded servers again, shedding a single server from
>      each (this brings them from having MAX regions to having MIN regions).
> 5. We now definitely have more regions that need assignment, either from the previous step or from the original shedding from overloaded
>      servers. Iterate the least loaded servers filling each to MIN. If we
>      still have more regions that need assignment, again iterate the least
>      loaded servers, this time giving each one (filling them to MAX) until
>      we run out.
> 6. All servers will now either host MIN or MAX regions. In addition, any server hosting >= MAX regions is guaranteed to end up with MAX
>      regions at the end of the balancing. This ensures the minimal number
>      of regions possible are moved.
>
> TODO: We can at-most reassign the number of regions away from a
>   particular server to be how many they report as most loaded. Should we
>   just keep all assignment in memory? Any objections? Does this mean we
>   need HeapSize on HMaster? Or just careful monitor? (current thinking
>   is we will hold all assignments in memory)

Comment: But if I will pre-split while creating table , it is guaranteed that it will create 5 regions each in different region server. right ?

Comment: It will create 5 regions, but the LoadBalancer will assign them based on the load (number of regions assigned) of each regionserver, it can happen that a regionserver gets two regions, or even 3. Anyway, I won't bother too much about it, you can manually move regions between regionservers if you need to (but the LoadBalancer can override it if needed) or even implement a custom load balancer. IMHO, I'll just create 10 regions instead of 5 and let the DefaultLoadBalancer do it's work as usual.

Answer (score 5):

If you have all the data have already been stored, I recommend you just move some regions to another region servers manually using [hbase shell](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell).

```
hbase> move ‘ENCODED_REGIONNAME’, ‘SERVER_NAME’
```

> Move a region. Optionally specify target regionserver else we choose
>   one at random. NOTE: You pass the encoded region name, not the region
>   name so this command is a little different to the others. The encoded
>   region name is the hash suffix on region names: e.g. if the region
>   name were
>   TestTable,0094429456,1289497600452.527db22f95c8a9e0116f0cc13c680396.
>   then the encoded region name portion is
>   527db22f95c8a9e0116f0cc13c680396 A server name is its host, port plus
>   startcode. For example: host187.example.com,60020,1289493121758

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Apache Phoenix for creating tables in HBase, you can specify SALT_BUCKETS in the CREATE statement. The table will split into as many regions as the bucket mentioned. Phoenix calculates the Hash of rowkey (most probably a numeric hash % SALT_BUCKETS) and assigns the column cell to the appropriate region.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS us_population (
      state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      city VARCHAR NOT NULL,
      population BIGINT
      CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (state, city)) SALT_BUCKETS=3;
```

This will pre-split the table into 3 regions

Alternatively, the HBase default UI, allows you to split regions accordingly.
[image]